# How to put pin on google map permanently that show our address?

Tags: android

I want to put information window on marker with one arrow button and text which used to get click in Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Maps SDK for Android you can use `GoogleMaps.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` to show your location permanently on the map.

Please see [at SDK Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29) for more infos or read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655).

Comment: I don't want to put my location but any address that is permanent. So, this is not about my location. refer link for example. Thanks